# how to change background color in html by using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table that odd lines in table have a origin `background-color`because of class `table-striped`.

I am willing add double click action for a table in html. `background-color` of a line(`tr`) should be changed if double click on it.  It seems I can't override the `background-color` when I double click on odd lines. What's wrong with my code?  Is there another way to override the background by using `jquery`?

Here are my code:

CSS style

```
.selected-hight {
        background-color: #FECA40;
    }    
.table-striped tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td, .table-striped tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
    background-color: #0e90d2;
    }
```

---

and JQuery method.

```
$(function() {
    $("table tbody").on("dblclick",'tr', function() {
        var rows = $('table tbody tr');
        rows.removeClass('selected-hight');
        $(this).addClass('selected-hight');
    });
});
```

---

and html code of table:

```
<table class="table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>head 1</td>
            <td>head 2</td>
        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>row 0, col 0</td>
            <td>row 0, col 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row 1, col 0</td>
            <td>row 0, col 1</td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: try adding !important to the background-color. This overrides the default color in bootstrap  e.g. background-color: #FECA40 !important;

Comment: the `background-color` can't be removed if I double click on another line if I add `!important`. that's not what I want.

Comment: Instead of assigning css for `td/th` elements...apply on `tr` as you are overriding class for `tr` elements... [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/3tch9ydg/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can override. Try to add a new class to avoid adding !important

```js
$(function() {
    $("table tbody").on("dblclick",'tr', function() {
        var rows = $('table tbody tr');
        rows.removeClass('selected-hight');
        $(this).addClass('selected-hight');
    });
});
```

```css
    .table-striped tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td, .table-striped tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
        background-color: #0e90d2;
        }
       
        
        .table-striped tbody > tr.selected-hight > td, .table-striped tbody > tr.selected-hight > th{
          background-color: #FECA40;          
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>head 1</td>
            <td>head 2</td>
        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>row 0, col 0</td>
            <td>row 0, col 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row 1, col 0</td>
            <td>row 0, col 1</td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's what I need. Thank you very much. And may I ask why my code cannot work?

Comment: your style is override because of predefined css ( .table-striped ). You must have to learn about overriding css in proper way.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS setting the other background-color is more specific than the class you add. See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/gv4gpaoL/1/) fiddle.

Instead of just:

```
.selected-hight {
  background-color: #FECA40;
}

.table-striped tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td, .table-striped tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
  background-color: #0e90d2;
}
```

Try this:

```
.table-striped tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td, .table-striped tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
  background-color: #0e90d2;
}

.table-striped tbody>tr.selected-hight>td,
.table-striped tbody>tr.selected-hight>th {
  background-color: #FECA40;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS and apply to table elements. It will change background color on click as well as onmouseover:-

```
.table-title h3 {
   color: #fafafa;
   font-size: 30px;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-style:normal;
   font-family: "Roboto", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
   text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   text-transform:uppercase;
}
.table-fill {
  background: white;
  border-radius:3px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding:5px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  animation: float 5s infinite;
}

th {
  color:#D5DDE5;;
  background:#1b1e24;
  border-bottom:4px solid #9ea7af;
  border-right: 1px solid #343a45;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding:5px;
  text-align:left;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  vertical-align:middle;
}

th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius:3px;
}

th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius:3px;
  border-right:none;
}

tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
  border-bottom-: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
  color:#666B85;
  padding:5px;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:normal;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.1);
}

tr:hover td {
  background:#4E5066;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #22262e;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #22262e;
}

tr:first-child {
  border-top:none;
}

tr:last-child {
  border-bottom:none;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background:#EBEBEB;
}

tr:nth-child(odd):hover td {
  background:#4E5066;
}

tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
}

tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
}

td {
  background:#FFFFFF;
  padding:5px;
  text-align:left;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight:300;
  font-size:14px;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-right: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
}

td:last-child {
  border-right: 0px;
}

th.text-left {
   text-align: left;
}

th.text-center {
   text-align: center;
}

 th.text-right {
   text-align: right;
}
```